# SQL Server big amout of data in one or more tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wonder what would be more efficient, storing big amounts of data in one or more tables.
Suppose we would like to store all vertecies of different terrain models.

**First solution** - In traditional way we can create two tables:
Table Terrain (id, name, description) and
Table Vertex (terrainId, x, y, z).

Then the vertexes for all terrains are stored in one table (the Vertex table) – this table can be very big (hundreds of millions of vertecies).

**Second solution** - create one table per set of vertexes.
Table Vertex-For-Terrein1(x, y, z),
Table Vertex-For-Terrein2(x, y, z),
…,
Table Vertex-For-Terreinn(x, y, z).

In the second way, the Vertex table don’t stores information about terrain (this  information is handled in table name e.g. Table Vertex-For-**Terrein1**).

What would be more efficient or have better performance?

Comment: Would you really want to end up with a database containing hundreds of millions of vertex tables? It would be an administrative nightmare, and would lead to extremely messy queries if you ask me. Or did I understand you wrong?

Comment: The table Vertex-For-Terrein1 contains all vertexes for terrain 1, The table Vertex-For-Terrein2 contains all vertexes for terrain 2 and so on (this is second solution in my post)

Comment: How many terrains do you have? Is this amount likely to change in the future, or is it completely static?

Comment: What for? I mean, you will ever quewry them or are they just there for trawing? In this case "usage" should drive requirements and design. It may be better to not store the vertives in a table fomat but binary.

Comment: @SchmitzIT: The numer of terrain tables is variable (not static).

Comment: @10gler - Definitely stick to solution 1. Your sanity will thank you in the long run :)

Comment: @TomTom: See my last comment in first answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First solution. Index the `Vertex` table on `terrainId`.

Second solution is a denormalisation that will make the data hard to maintain. If your requirements are limited enough for the second solution to be more suitable you probably don't need a RDBMS system.

Comment: Yes of course I understand this problem (Second solution is a denormalisation). Now I have an index on terrainId (first solution). I wonder if second solution even it is a denormalisation could be more efficient.

Comment: Well, if you overlook the task of identifying the correct table, then the second solution is more efficient for reading the verticies for a specific terrain. It avoids the index seek but, that is not especially expensive. The second dolution backfires when you perform any operation that spans terrains. if you require no such operations, do you need to store the data in a relational database?

Comment: There would be two main operations: read and modify vertexes of specified terrain.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the first solution, you might want to look into partitioning your table by a function of the terrain id to each individual terrain manageable yet having the flexibility of a normalised design...

Comment: I think the first solution is better + data partitioning. Thanks beny23!

Comment: Partitioning makes sense, assuming you have the right version of SQL Server.

Comment: Here is good description of partitioning: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you will be querying this data. Probably the each vertex can be stored in Vertext table only in one row as varchar(max).